# How to get the list of calling application (Intent.ACTION_CALL) in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to get **packageName** of calling application (phone). I've tried following but it is giving me blank list.

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
    val resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
    if (resolveInfos != null && resolveInfos.isNotEmpty()) {
        Timber.i("resolve info %s", resolveInfos)
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably need an `Intent` with a `Uri` for a `tel:` value.

Comment: It just worked, Thanks